# Issue with inserting split percentage using trigger

Tags: trigger, map, collection

I am beginner to salesforce. I am trying to insert an opportunity split record whenever an opportunity team member is inserted.

Trigger code:

```
trigger OpportunityTeamMembertrigger on OpportunityTeamMember(before insert, after insert, before update, after update, before delete, after delete) {
    if (Trigger.IsAfter) {
        if (Trigger.isInsert) {
            Opportunitysplithandler is = new Opportunitysplithandler(Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.newMap);
            is.insertoppsplit();
        }
        if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
            Opportunitysplithandler is = new Opportunitysplithandler(Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.newMap);
            is.insertoppsplit();
        }
        if (Trigger.isDelete) {}
    }
}
```

I am trying to insert using following code:

```
public class Opportunitysplithandler{  
    Map<Id, OpportunityTeamMember> oldotm;  
    Map<Id, OpportunityTeamMember> newotm;  
    List<OpportunitySplit> oppts = new List<OpportunitySplit>();  
    public Opportunitysplithandler(Map<Id, OpportunityTeamMember> oldtriggerotm, Map<Id, OpportunityTeamMember> newtriggerotm){  
        oldotm=oldtriggerotm;  
        newotm=newtriggerotm;  
    }  
   public void insertoppsplit (){  
        for(OpportunityTeamMember o: newotm.values()){  
        OpportunitySplit os1 = new OpportunitySplit();  
        os1.OpportunityId = o.OpportunityId ;  
        os1.SplitOwnerId = o.UserId;  
        os1.SplitPercentage = o.opportunity.Upsell_Percent__c;  
        system.debug('bbbbbbbbbb : '+ o.Opportunity.Upsell_Percent__c);  
        oppts.Add(os1);  
        }   
    insert oppts;  
    }  
}
```

In debug statement it is showing as null.
Can you please suggest how can i over come this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your trigger as well? I'm not sure where and how you call the insertoppsplit method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Opportunitysplithandler{  
  Map<Id, OpportunityTeamMember> oldotm;  
  Map<Id, OpportunityTeamMember> newotm;  
  List<OpportunitySplit> oppts = new List<OpportunitySplit>();  
  public Opportunitysplithandler(Map<Id, OpportunityTeamMember> oldtriggerotm, Map<Id, OpportunityTeamMember> newtriggerotm){  
    oldotm=oldtriggerotm;  
    newotm=newtriggerotm;  
}  
public void insertoppsplit (){  
  Set<Id> oppId=new set<Id>();
  for(OpportunityTeamMember opmem:newotm.values()){
         oppId.add(opmem.OpportunityId);
  }
  map<Id,Opportunity> mapIdByOpp=new map<Id,Opportunity>([select Id,Upsell_Percent__c from Opportunity where Id IN:oppId]);//query and store Opportunity data in Map 
    for(OpportunityTeamMember o: newotm.values()){  
      OpportunitySplit os1 = new OpportunitySplit();  
       os1.OpportunityId = o.OpportunityId ;  
       os1.SplitOwnerId = o.UserId;  
       os1.SplitPercentage = (mapIdByOpp.get(o.opportunityId)).Upsell_Percent__c;  
       system.debug('bbbbbbbbbb : '+ os1.SplitPercentage);  
       oppts.Add(os1);  
    }   
   insert oppts; //Do exception Handling here 
  }  
}
```

> Relationship Fields in Trigger Context yields null .You will need to requery it to reflect the value .Please check my updated class

Comment: Mark as answered and Upvote if answers help :)

Answer (score 1):

As Mohith said, you're using a parent field within your trigger, but Salesforce hasn't retrieved this from the database.  The line in question is:

```
os1.SplitPercentage = o.opportunity.Upsell_Percent__c;
```

When running a trigger, Salesforce has access to all the fields on the object that caused the trigger.  In your case, it's the `OpportunityTeamMember` object.  You want to retrieve a value from the parent Opportunity record, so you'll need to query the database for it.

In the following sample code, I've queried the database before the for loop and added it to a Map.  You can then easily reference the map while in the for loop.

I'd probably structure your class a bit differently to make it easier to read, and easier to call from the trigger.

```
public class Opportunitysplithandler{  

    public static void insertoppsplit (Map<Id, OpportunityTeamMember> oldtriggerotm, Map<Id, OpportunityTeamMember> newtriggerotm) {

        List<OpportunitySplit> oppts = new List<OpportunitySplit>();  

        // get the Upsell Percent from the parent Opportunities
        List<Id, Opportunity> parentOpps = [SELECT Upsell_Percent__c FROM Opporuntity WHERE Id IN :newtriggerotm.keySet()] ;

        // Loop through the OTMs and create some splits
        for(OpportunityTeamMember o: newotm.values()){  
            OpportunitySplit os1 = new OpportunitySplit();  
            os1.OpportunityId = o.OpportunityId ;  
            os1.SplitOwnerId = o.UserId;  
            os1.SplitPercentage = parentOpps.get(o.OpportunityId);  
            system.debug('bbbbbbbbbb : '+ o.Opportunity.Upsell_Percent__c);  
            oppts.Add(os1);
        }

        // insert the splits
        insert oppts;  
    }
}
```

Note the use of the `static` keyword on the method declaration.  This makes it so you don't need to instantiate a Opportunitysplithandler record to invoke the method.  You can then update your trigger to:

```
trigger OpportunityTeamMembertrigger on OpportunityTeamMember(before insert, after insert, before update, after update, before delete, after delete) {
    if (Trigger.IsAfter) {
        if (Trigger.isInsert) {
            Opportunitysplithandler.insertoppsplit(Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.newMap);
        }
        if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
            Opportunitysplithandler.insertoppsplit(Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.newMap);
        }
        if (Trigger.isDelete) {}
    }
}
```